# Unable to initialize GoogleMap object in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Attempting to create a member variable mMap throws an error "Classifier GoogleMap does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here". In Java, I would have just used "Private GoogleMap mMap".

Help is appreciated!

```
private val TAG = "MapActivity"

private val FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
private val COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
private val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

private var mLocationPermissionGranted : Boolean = false
private var mMap = GoogleMap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize GoogleMap like this

```
 private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap? = null
```

Implement the OnMapReadyCallback interface and use the onMapReady(GoogleMap) callback method to get a handle to the GoogleMap object. The GoogleMap object is the internal representation of the map itself. To set the view options for a map, you modify its GoogleMap object.

```
class MainActivity : OnMapReadyCallback {

  // your other code

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
mMap = googleMap  

if (mMap != null) {
    val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)

    if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    } else {
        requestPermission(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE)
     }
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to apply it

> private lateinit var map: GoogleMap? = null

but I'm getting

> 'lateinit' modifier is not allowed on properties of nullable types