# lateinit property map has not been initialized

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

Initially the only Activity I have is MapsActivity with the following snippet :

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
```

When I created a MainActivity in Java source codes, I called the MapActivity like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
```

But now, I am getting ***lateinit property map has not been initialized***

I tried what was advised [here][1] but it says ***lateinit modifier is not allowed***
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076696/unable-to-initialize-googlemap-object-in-kotlin

Comment: Can you show exactly what you tried? As I would assume `private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap? = null` would fix your issue

Comment: @DavidKroukamp you can't assign a null or any value to a lateinit val/var

Comment: @padlanau can you share your whole class and where you want to use the object map?

Comment: If that's the case then OP should simply do `private var map: GoogleMap? = null` and check for null before using `map` property

Comment: The point of ``lateinit`` is to avoid making things nullable just so you can initialise them later. The OP's problem is they're promising to initialise ``map`` before anything accesses it, but something is reading the value before it's set

Comment: @MahmoudOmara  Originally, I have only one activity called MapsActivity in Kotlin. The source is from here [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/230-introduction-to-google-maps-api-for-android-with-kotlin). It was working fine. Then when I created ActivityMain and inside it, I called MapsActivity (through Intent, see my code above) , then the initialized error comes up. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Yes. The studio is advising me to remove 'lateinit' modifier. I will give it a try.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp  The studio is advising me as well those using the variable map like _map.isMyLocationEnabled = true_ to **Replace with safe(?.) call**

Comment: @cactustictacs Yes you are correct. I'm thinking the same thing. I explained my case to Mahmoud above. It was ok when I only got MapsActivity in my project. The issue started when I created an ActivityMain where I put my Google-Firebase login logic and call MapsActivty if it is a successful login

Comment: the moment you call an activity through an intent, this activity will replace the one currently visible, you cannot display 2 activities in the same screen

Comment: and since u declared the map object as optional above, you will use it like this, map?.isMyLocationEnabled = true

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudOmara. I was able to solve it. See below.. Seems to working now.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I initialized/fixed map

```
private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
private val SYDNEY = LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689)
.
.
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
        mapFragment!!.getMapAsync { googleMap ->
            map = googleMap
            marker = googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().title("Sydney").position(SYDNEY))
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(SYDNEY, 15f))
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10f), 2000, null)
        }
```

Comment: i would suggest replacing the !! for a ?.let call, this will prevent your app crashing at any given point

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudOmara. I just started learning Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid errors when using the lateinit googleMap var, best to only use the var when the map object value has been assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `lateinit property map has not been initialized` because that property it's being read before it has been assigned any value.

If you can't ensure that it will be used only after you have assigned any value, then it's better to use a `private var map: GoogleMap? = null` and check if that's null before reading it.